# Accessing SFR (Special Function Registers) on a 32 bit controller

Tags: c, embedded

How can I access SFR (Special Function Registers) for a memory mapped peripheral.

And how can I be sure that the compiler does not mess up the endianness?

As an example, How can access the 32 bit register at address `0x00080`, and how are the bits mapped? Please don't be shy about going into details and low level.

Comment: FWIW, there is no existing tag `sfr` yet. I don't think it should be created just for this.

Comment: And another hint: [SFR Definitions](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/c51/c51_lib_sfrdefs.htm). This seems to be valid for Cx51 processors only.

Comment: `sfr`, `sfr16`, and `sbit` may be compiler extensions specific to your toolchain and target architecture or they may be type aliases defined in a target specific header.  Either way you would do well to specify both the toolchain and the target to get any kind of useful answer.  On most architectures SFRs (or on-chip peripheral registers more generally) and memory mapped, so access is just like accessing any other memory - but must be declared `volatile`.  Most targets do not have bit addressable memory or SFRs - 8051 is one that does, but that is not 32 bit.

Comment: @Clifford I have tried to simplify my question. My device has memory mapped peripheral. The TMR0 (32 bit) corresponds to byte 0x80. How can I access this memory location, and how is endianess handled?

Comment: KEY question:  what CPU?  Without that important detail, any response will be a WAG.

Answer (score 1):

Most toolchains or chip-vendors will provide a target specific header file with support for this.  However if you need to create your own then you might for example define:

```
volatile uint32_t* TMR0_ADDR = 0x00080 ;
#define TMR0 (*TMR0_ADDR) ;
```

The you can assign TMR0 directly: for example:

```
TMR0 = 0x80000000 ;
```

With respect to how bits are mapped, the asme as they are for memory (they are after all memory mapped), so 0x00000001 sets the LSB and 0x80000000 sets the MSB.  If you want to map individual bit fields within the register, then you can use a bitfield struct (rather than `uint32_t` as above) - the implementation of bitfield structs is however compiler specific, so a target specific header you produce for one compiler may not be portable to others.  That is why you should use the toolchain provided header where possible.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the compiler you are using, many compilers provide ***at*** keyword which can be used to put a variable, then that can be used to access the sfr:

```
volatile uint32_t sfrVariable _at_ 0x00080;
sfrVariable = 0;
```

In case you are using GCC, it wont allow you to do this, in that case you will have to use:

```
#define sfrVariable         (*(volatile uint32_t *) 0x00080) 
sfrVariable = 0;
```

By default the compiler will run little-endian, but mostly uint doesn't get affected by it as its already a little-endian type.